# GridView Obter Valor TextBox

Tags: c#, gridview

Pretendo obter o valor de uma `textbox` de uma `gridview`. Esta Textbox é criada pelo `RowDataBound`.
Da seguinte Forma:

```
TextBox txtValor = new TextBox();
e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(txtValor);
```

Pois a `gridview` é dinâmica e não é possível utilizar o `templatefield`.

Já tentei os seguintes métodos:

```
TextBox textBox = row.Cells[j].FindControl("txtValor") as TextBox;
string quantidade = ((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Controls[1])).Text.ToString();
```

Comment: Ao percorrer o gridview pretendo guardar o valor numa lista.

Comment: Preciso de mais detalhes... faz o seguinte, tenta setar a propriedade ID do TextBox antes de adicionar ele nas células, e depois só procura com o FindControl por aquela ID, visto que o nome txtValor é o nome da variável que está guardando uma referência ao objeto, mas o objeto em sí não teve seu ID preenchido. Além do mais, nessa tentativa: `string quantidade = ((TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Controls[1])).Text.ToString();` você está pesquisando pelo segundo controle dentro da célula, isso está correto? Você tem outros controles dentro da célula?

Comment: tentei desta forma:
 TextBox txtValor = new TextBox();
                    txtValor.Width = 15;
                    txtValor.ID = "txt"

depois para ler:
 TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].FindControl("txt"));
a mytextbox da null;

Answer (score 1):

Criei um exemplo, porque, do modo que você está fazendo logo após o recarregamento da página ele vai perder toda as referências dos controles adicionados:

***Crie somente 1 `TemplateField` e coloque o componente `TextBox` com o Id `TxtValor`.***

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridDados" ClientIDMode="Static" ViewStateMode="Enabled" ValidateRequestMode="Enabled">
    <Columns>               
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtValor" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="ButPesquisar" runat="server" Text="Pesquisar" OnClick="ButPesquisar_Click" />
<asp:Label Text="" ID="LblResultado" runat="server" />
```

***Carregando essa GridView:***

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Grid();

    }
}
private void Grid()
{   
    GridDados.DataSource = (new object[]
    {
        new { id = 1, nome = "teste 1"},
        new { id = 2, nome = "teste 2"}
    })
    .ToArray();

    GridDados.DataBind();

}
```

***No button `ButPesquisar` no seu método `ButPesquisar_Click` coloque:***

```
protected void ButPesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

       LblResultado.Text = string.Empty;
       foreach (GridViewRow item in GridDados.Rows)
       {
           TextBox txtValor = item.FindControl("TxtValor") as TextBox;
           if (txtValor != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtValor.Text))
           {
               LblResultado.Text += txtValor.Text;
               LblResultado.Text += "<br>";
           }
      }
}
```

***Resultado:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, os dados são carregados dinamicamente, mas, o `TextBox` dentro do `TemplateField` é fixo.

***Recomendação***

*Se puder faça GridView formatado, com os `DataField` já estipulados com `TemplateField` se precisar, essas criações dinâmicas trazem mais problemas do que solução.*

Comment: O problema e que tanto as linhas, colunas são dinâmicas não existe um número certo. Não sei se este método serve

Comment: @user6018 na sua questão você deveria ser mais especifico e mostrar o que está fazendo são poucas informações ...

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)

{

e.NewValues["email"]=((TextBox)((GridView)sender).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("MeuTextBox")).Text;

}
```

isso no rowupdating!!! senão num tem como saber qual linha que vc alterou o mail!

mas creio que a questão no caso de do Bind

vai na templatecolumn clica com o botão direito no textbox e e coloque `Bind("Email")`